# Passing a C array to a struct initializer in a vector brace initialization

Tags: c++

First, I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355533/initializing-struct-vector-with-brace-enclosed-initializer-list).

I'm curious why the following does not work:

```
float vcolor[4]{color.getX(),color.getY(),color.getZ(),1.0f};
float v1[3]{from.getX(),from.getY(),from.getZ()};
float v2[3]{to.getX(),to.getY(),to.getZ()};
std::vector<Vertex> v={{v1,vcolor},{v2,vcolor}};
```

> No matching constructor for initialization of
>   'std::vector'

But instead passing the elements directly works fine (as noted in the other question):

```
std::vector<Vertex> v={
    {{from.getX(),from.getY(),from.getZ()},
        {color.getX(),color.getY(),color.getZ(),1.0f}},
    {{to.getX(),to.getY(),to.getZ()},
        {color.getX(),color.getY(),color.getZ(),1.0f}}};
```

Shouldn't the former also be possible?

Comment: `{v1,vcolor},{v2,vcolor}` doesn't form an initializer list.

Comment: @Lingxi thanks but.. they are inside another pair of braces, which would be an initializer list, no?

Comment: Just looked at the definition of `Vertex`. The problem is you cannot copy initialize arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple explanation. You can initialize an array using aggregate initialization syntax as `float arr[4] = { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f }`. That's why `Vertex v = { {1.f, 2.f, 3.f}, {1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f} }` works. What you can't do is copy-initializing an array from another one. So

```
float arr[4] = { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f };
float brr[4] = arr;
```

doesn't work. So, ultimately, in your question, the first form doesn't work.

Comment: `arr[4]` doesn't name the first array anyway. It names the one-past-the-end element of that array. Your final example should be `float brr[4] = arr;`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My fault. Thanks for the kind mention :-)

Answer (score 0):

Lets look in more detail what you are trying to do here:

```
std::vector<Vertex> v={
    {{from.getX(),from.getY(),from.getZ()},
        {color.getX(),color.getY(),color.getZ(),1.0f}},
    {{to.getX(),to.getY(),to.getZ()},
        {color.getX(),color.getY(),color.getZ(),1.0f}}};
```

You try to initialize a Vector with two elements, which are initialized with

```
{{from.getX(),from.getY(),from.getZ()},
    {color.getX(),color.getY(),color.getZ(),1.0f}}
```

and

```
{{to.getX(),to.getY(),to.getZ()},
    {color.getX(),color.getY(),color.getZ(),1.0f}}
```

Those again are initializer lists, which C++ tries to convert to a Vertex. Sinze they contain two elements, which itself are initializer lists containing 3(4) floats. (at least i assume your `getX/Y/Z()` return floats), everything is fine and they are used to initialize the arrays inside each Vertex. This is somewhat equivalent to the calls

```
Vertex{{from.getX(),from.getY(),from.getZ()},
        {color.getX(),color.getY(),color.getZ(),1.0f}};

float position[3]{from.getX(),from.getY(),from.getZ()};
float color[4]{color.getX(),color.getY(),color.getZ(),1.0f};
```

Now lets see your second case:

```
std::vector<Vertex> v={{v1,vcolor},{v2,vcolor}};
```

Again, each of the containig initializer lists is "mapped" to one Vertex, giving calls like:

```
Vertex{v1,vcolor}
```

But v1 and vcolor are no initializer list, they are just a pointer to float (`float*`)

And just as you can not do

```
float v3[3]{v1};
```

or more obvious

```
float* f = new float;
float v[3]{f};
```

theres no way to initialize an array from a `float*`

You could try to use std::arrays instead and use their Iterator-based construction. Or you could try to write proper constructors for your Vertex. Or you could store the initializer list as initializer list until you actually form the Vertex. Either way, constructing your Vertex in multiple steps will be a bit more work.

Comment: If his `Vertex` has a range-based constructor, he could use `{std::begin(vX), std::end(vX), std::begin(vcolor), std::end(vcolor)}` for each vertex, even with C-style arrays.